# avoiding a for loop to convert date/time string to number

Tags: matlab, date, time

I am looking for some expression that would help me avoiding to do a for loop as I have more than 2000000 lines.
So first, I need to get date and time which are in string ('yyyy-mm-dd') and ('dd:mm:ss') to a timevec or time number;

I have started the following;

```
n=length(TEMP);
for i5=1:n
date_tmp(i5,:)=sscanf(TEMP.Date(1,:),'%4d-%2d-%2d');
time_tmp(i5,:)=sscanf(TEMP.Time(1,:),'%2d:%2d:%2d');
datetime_tmp(i5,:)=[date_tmp(i5,:),time_tmp(i5,:)];
i5
end
```

Obviously this should be written much better,
Any help welcome,
Thanks

Comment: `TEMP` appears to be a structure array with fields `Date` and `Time`. Is this correct? What size are the fields (i.e. are they single line strings or multi-row character arrays)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datevec`, no need to loop over anything:

```
datevec(["2016-06-02 01:04:02","2016-06-02 01:04:01"])
ans =
    2016           6           2           1           4           2
    2016           6           2           1           4           1
```

EDIT: As Hoki pointed out, you can just as easily do this with `datenum` (or indeed with `datetime`), if you would prefer a datenum or datetime object. The syntax is exactly the same, just replace `datevec` with either `datenum` or `datetime`.

Comment: you could also give an example with `datenum` since the usage is the same and the OP mentionned he was interested in that too.

Comment: That's true. I have added an addendum to the answer.

Comment: Indeed that works! thank you. However, I have my time written as '03:10:05.000' which then does not work... so I can only use the datevec outside the forloop for the date, not the time, then I can combine them together I guess.

Comment: You could concatenate the dates and the times together?